# Automating Testing of GUI in TCL/TK - Record and Replay - Bwidget & TTK Tree

Tags: user-interface, automated-tests, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a task to automate the superficial testing of a GUI created using TCL/TK and I have been searching for different ways to do it, my first step would be to test the buttons and I also have to test a very lengthy Data Tree. I came across the Record the mouse buttons and then reuse them to test the GUI, but I cannot comprehend the principle, I cant understand what is " Record " and " Reuse " and can it be used to test a BWidget Tree or a Ttk tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"[Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) is a visual technology to automate and test graphical user interfaces using screenshot images..."*

As the description says, **it's screenshot based**, so it isn't aware about the framework (Tcl/Tk) or types of objects (*"BWidget Tree or a Ttk tree"*) being tested.

I've used it sometimes, it does what it promises well, but you'd have to evaluate whether it suits your needs or not.